# Can't connect to Azure SQL database from Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, azure

When I try to open my Azure SQL Server database in Visual Studio
[image]

and then use my Azure user account (I already added this user to SQL Owner role) UserName@DomainName.com I got the following error

Cannot open server "DomainName.com" requested by the login.  The login failed. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 40532)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems to be I need to use **UserName@DomainName.com@AzureSQLInstanceName** as a user name, and my domain password as password.
I got that from the database connection strings section on Azure portal.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you've added the IP address you are calling from the to SQL Firewall:  Your Server >> Settings >> Firewall Settings.

Answer (score 3):

Just to summerize the above:-

- I went to the Azure database Connection Strings and selected ODBC.
- Then I used the value from Server= for the server and from Uid= as the username and my password and it worked.
- If this doesn't work, check the firewall.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problems were:

1. I had forgot to add a firewall rule stating I could access the database from my IP address; when you get to the firewall rules it shows your current IP address and a line to create a rule. There is also a button that say "add the client IP" or similar, just click it.

Also I forgot to save the rules (there is a not that clear "save" button or string in the top right above the rules)

2. I was using id + password as myname@hotmail.com + mypass; I would get a complain about not able to access "... .hotmail. I changed tue aID to my name only.
3. Also I was not using the full string "tcp:my-database-name.database.windows.net,1433" I guess it is necessary, not sure.

Fixed the 3 points above it worked.