# SQL Server login with @

Tags: sql-server, authentication, azure-sql-database

I created a login/password for an Azure SQL server and I put an @ in the login.
Now when I try to connect to the SQL server, it fails because it take the right part after the @ as the server name:

> Cannot open server "domain.fr" requested by the login.  The login
>   failed. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 40532)

[image: screenshot]

Does anyone know how to escape the @ in the login or any other solution?

Comment: you need to use @instancename,this is due to the way you created login ,see this answer for example:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32162041/cant-connect-to-azure-sql-database-from-visual-studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a bit tricky, since in Azure SQL Database, strings after @ is recognized as the server name. to make it work, use email@domain.fr **@xxx** as login instead.

Answer (score 2):

It's generally bad practice to use special characters in object names (the only real exception, in my opinion, is with Windows Logins and users, which contain a \ due to them being in the format Domain\User).

When passing object names with special characters, you need to quote them using brackets. Thus the login name you would pass would be `[@Login]` (replacing *login* with the actual login name) or `[StackOverflow\Larnu]`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately using `[email@domain.fr]` instead of `email@domain.fr` doesn't work. I get the same error.

Comment: If you're using SSMS, you don't need to quote it (I assumed you were using some kind of connection string). Simply using the login name will work. For example I just created a login `[Larnu@StackOverflow.com]` on my Sandbox server, and connected by simply entering "Larnu@StackOverflow.com" in the Login field. What do the SQL Server Logs say?

Comment: I am using SSMS to connect. The SQL server is on Azure. And unfortunately as there is only one user on Azure SQL server I can't login to see the logs.