# Azure - 'There was an error while initializing App Service app for blahblahapp' 'Error connecting to SQL server (SQL error code 40532)'

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm following a tutorial for setting up easy tables in Azure but I'm getting 'There was an error while initializing App Service app for 'blahblahapp'. 'Error connecting to SQL server (SQL error code 40532)'.

My connection string is:

Data Source=tcp:blahblahapp.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=blahblahapp_db;User ID=myemail@email.com;Password=blahblahpassword.

I've had a similar problem before while following another tutorial where my sql connection credentials were copied from the connection string given by Azure and pasted into a visualstudio c# program but it came up with errors and would not connect using the username myemail@email.com instead of the username given which was the same myemail@email.com I had to put myemail@email.com@database.azurewebsites.net so I'm thinking this could be the problem.

Or is it????

This problem is happening in the Azure console but how do I edit the connection string given by azure so that it is myemail@email.com@database.azurewebsites.net?

Comment: i've managed to edit the connection string in Application Settings in the azure console but still getting the error so i changed it back to the original myemail@email.com but still geting the error. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Check the firewall and add your IP in that, refer this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32162041/cant-connect-to-azure-sql-database-from-visual-studio)